# No duplicate props allowed react/jsx-no-duplicate-props

Tags: reactjs

I am getting this error on line **Grid item** :

```
<Grid container spacing={3} className='centerd-text' >
     <Grid item xs={12} xs={12} md={4} >
          <img src={img01} alt="img" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please remove one `xs={12}` in `Grid`